# ExpandableListView CheckBox doesn't trigger onClick event

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

In my ExpandableListView, each child row contains a CheckBox and a TextView. Everything works perfectly (finally!) when I tap on the TextView. However, when I tap on the Checkbox, its state changes, but the onClick event never fires. There are no errors, but nothing really happens.

I want both the textview and the checkbox to invoke the same behavior (i.e. the user should be able to click anywhere on the row and the same behavior will result). What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,  View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

        view = getCategoryChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //this works for the textview click but
                    //doesn't fire when the check box is clicked 
                    System.err.println("child clicked");
                }
            });

        return view;
    }

    private View getCategoryChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, View view) {

        ClientFinderCategories child = (ClientFinderCategories) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item_category, null);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
            holder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand_list_item);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }       

        try {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(child.getIsSelected());
            holder.textView.setText(child.getCategory());   
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        return view;
    }

}
```

layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_box"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expand_list_item"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/smart_finder_settings_font_size"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a view contained in another view (here: `CheckBox` in `LinearLayout`) handles a click itself (which CheckBox does whereas TextView was set `android:clickable="false"`) then the OnClickListener of the containing view isn't called.

Call `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` on the `CheckBox` itself to install an appropriate listener.

Comment: Calling setOnCheckedChangeListener is a little problematic since that method is the the Activity class whereas my onClickListener is in my BaseExpandableListAdapter. But you made me realize that all I have to do is to add android:clickable="false" to my checkbox (just like I have it for my textview). That solves the whole problem. Thanks!